# cat(3,A,B) Matlab func. equivalent in opencv3 (c++)

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, opencv3.0

Is there any function in opencv which can store multiple matrices in the same way as Matlab cat(3,A,B) function does?

I think cv::hconcat() and vconcat() can not handle it.

**Edit**

merge(vector-containing-matrices, output container) works but it is important to have the same depth for all matrices

Comment: Also see [merge](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge) in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Use OpenCV's merge function, as follows:

```
//defines matrics to concat alond 3rd dimensions
cv::Mat M1 = cv::Mat::ones(5, 5, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat M2 = cv::Mat::ones(5, 5, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat M3 = cv::Mat::ones(5, 5, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat M4 = cv::Mat::ones(5, 5, CV_8UC1);
//defines a vector to hold these matrices
std::vector<cv::Mat> vec;
vec.push_back(M1);
vec.push_back(M2);
vec.push_back(M3);
vec.push_back(M4);
//concatanated them using merge function
cv::Mat outMat;
cv::merge(vec, outMat);
```